# How to retrieve only matched embedded documents in mongodb text index search

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb document as given below , i have configured text index on `messageTopic`, `messageTopicQuestion` and `answer` fields, 
if i search with any string then only matched embedded records should appear in the result not the entire document.

For example in below document if i search with word "private" then only in search result only first embedded document should come , how retrieve only matched embeeded documents in text search and exclude un matched embedded documents.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("586e8efdde81e56032000084"),
    "messageTopic": "My Private",
    "messageText": [{
        "messageTopicQuestion": "agent private",
        "answer": "agent private",
        "_id": ObjectId("586e8efdde81e56032000085"),
        "keywords": ["private"]
    }, {
        "messageTopicQuestion": "Greetings Checking",
        "answer": "Heloo I am good What about u",
        "_id": ObjectId("586fc80ccced739407000f4e"),
        "keywords": ["Hi-Good", "Heloo"]
    }],
    "__v": 3
}
```

I am using below script

```
db.getCollection('messagetemplates').aggregate([{
                 $match: {

                     $text: {$search: 'private'},
                     visible: 'PUB'
                 }
             },{ $sort: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } }])
```

Expecting below result.

```
{
        "_id": ObjectId("586e8efdde81e56032000084"),
        "messageTopic": "My Private",
        "messageText": [{
            "messageTopicQuestion": "agent private",
            "answer": "agent private",
            "_id": ObjectId("586e8efdde81e56032000085"),
            "keywords": ["private"]
        }],
        "__v": 3
    }
```

but unmatched embedded document also resulting as shown in below.

```
{
        "_id": ObjectId("586e8efdde81e56032000084"),
        "messageTopic": "My Private",
        "messageText": [{
            "messageTopicQuestion": "agent private",
            "answer": "agent private",
            "_id": ObjectId("586e8efdde81e56032000085"),
            "keywords": ["private"]
        }, {
            "messageTopicQuestion": "Greetings Checking",
            "answer": "Heloo I am good What about u",
            "_id": ObjectId("586fc80ccced739407000f4e"),
            "keywords": ["Hi-Good", "Heloo"]
        }],
        "__v": 3
    }
```

Comment: Based on your example what are you executing, what is your current result and what is your desired result?

Comment: Hi DaveCoast, could you please help i have updated my question

Comment: Don't think you can use text search to return an embedded document since the text search `$match` needs to be the first step in the aggregation pipeline. Have you considered using `$unwind` on `messageText` (since it is an array) to create a separate document for each array element and then `$regex` to select?

Comment: Hi DaveCoast, Thanks for your response , I tried using $unwind , but when using $unwind i am not able to use text search, Is there any workaround for our issue.